# How can I update a complex knockout observable programatically?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using durandal/requirejs/knockout here.
I'm also using the coderenaissance plugin for mapping (ko.viewmodel.updateFromModel(zitem, data).)

I'm getting the following data from my ajax call which I'm mapping into my zitem observable.

```
{
    "itemNumber" : "ABATAH000",
    "effectiveDate" : "2015-11-03T15:30:05.7118023-05:00",
    "expiryDate" : "2015-05-03T15:30:05.7118023-04:00",
    "minimumPremium" : 25,
    "zSubItems" : [{
            "zSubItemName" : "Mine",
            "unitDistance" : 100000,
            "zSubSubItems" : [{
                    "zSubSubItemName" : "CoverageA",
                    "zSubSubItemPremium" : 100.0,
                    "id" : 0
                }
            ],
            "id" : 1
        }
    ],
    "id" : 0
}
```

And here is the viewmodel I'm using:

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout', 'services/datacontext'],
    function (http, app, ko, datacontext) {
    var zitem = ko.observable();

    var activate = function () {
        //This is just a wrapper around an ajax call.
        return datacontext.getPolicy("value")
            .then(function(data) {
                ko.viewmodel.updateFromModel(zitem, data);
            });
    };

    var updateMinimumPremium = function (thisItem) {
        //This doesn't work
        zitem.minimumPremium(thisItem.minimumPremium + 1);
    };

    return {
        displayName: 'zitem example',
        zitem: zitem,
        updateMinimumPremium: updateMinimumPremium,
        activate: activate

    };
});
```

I'm binding the updateMinimumPremium to a click on a button at the same level as the minimumPremium element.

```
<button data-bind="click: $parent.updateMinimumPremium">Add 1</button>
```

How can I update [minimumPremium] or [zSubSubItemPremium] programatically?

Comment: may be ...  zitem.minimumPremium(thisItem.minimumPremium() + 1);  ... minimumPremium would be observable.

Comment: What does not work? The redraw of your view, when the value changes?

Comment: @Sam.C unfortunately thisItem comes from the parameter which doesn't seem to be observable(as opposed to the zitem declared above of which all items are observable.)

Comment: I am referring to "minimumPremium" as an observable not "thisItem". it should be an observable, otherwise the zitem.minimumPremium( ... would not work in the first place, it should give you a javascript error at this point if that is not the case). And in that same line you adding "1" (thisItem.minimumPremium + 1) where it should have been "thisItem.minimumPremium() + 1".

Comment: looking back at your question, it requires a little bit of clarification, I have hacked a working code from your mark up in this jsfiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/5oLtz0xa/9/"  ... review the script and add some clarification to your question if you can

Comment: @Sam.C Thanks for the link you pointed me to the solution.  I was using the other mapping plugin incorrectly (http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/)  and the child objects weren't being rendered as observable.  Once I switched to the 'official' mapping plugin everything now works as expected.

Comment: Glad I could shade some light :)

Comment: @Sam.C  Your first comment is actually the right answer.  Can I mark it as the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"minimumPremium" would be observable

```
zitem.minimumPremium(thisItem.minimumPremium() + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `zitem` is observable as well, so try this:

```
zitem().minimumPremium(thisItem.minimumPremium + 1);
```

In real application don't forget to check the value of `zitem()` call - it can be uninitialized.